# Is a familiar with the figment archetype still cursed, diseased, or poisoned after it dies then returns?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars, archetype

Do Figment Archetype Familiar with Lycanthropy retain Lycanthropy after returning from death?

> Recurring Dream (Su): Pathfinder Ultimate Wilderness
>
> A figment has a total number of hit points equal to 1/4 of its master’s total hit points. ***If the figment dies, it vanishes, appearing again with 1 hit point after its master awakens from a full night’s sleep.*** If a figment ever strays more than 100 feet from its master or enters an antimagic field, or if a figment’s master is unconscious or asleep, the figment disappears until the next time its master prepares spells or regains her spells per day. Because it is a being of its master’s mind, a figment can never serve as a witch’s familiar, a shaman’s spirit animal, or any other spell-granting familiar, and it can’t use any divination spells or spell-like abilities the base creature has.

So if the familiar gets lycanthropy and dies by being killed or being more than 100 feet from its master; when they come back when the master regains or prepares spells "after a long rest", are they still stricken by lycanthropy?

Comment: Is there a way to get a creature that has the humanoid type as a familiar? If there's not, the question isn't moot: Just change it to *Is a familiar with the figment archetype still cursed, diseased, or poisoned after it dies then returns?* (That is, if the underlying problem is whether the reborn creature is a new creature or the old creature just reconstituted is what really needs addressing rather than lycanthropy specifically. If not, never mind.)

Comment: The familiar in question is that of a sprite a diminutive fey which can be chosen with the Improved Familiar feat. The imagined image of that figment familiar is that of a sprite, so yes it humanoid. Which had lead me to ask, can familiars be cursed, diseased or prisoned?

Comment: The [sprite](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/sprite/) has a creature type of fey (although it is humanoid in shape), and "[l]ycanthropes are humanoids with the ability to turn into animals and animal-humanoid hybrid shapes" ([here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/lycanthrope/)) When a text says *humanoids* in a context like that, it generally means creature type not shape, but if your GM has a different read, that's cool.

Comment: So if it dies by definition of death; wouldn't that mean that if the figment familiar returns when the master recovers their spells, the figment familiar is resurrected? Would that be a true resurrection, in which case lycanthropy is negated or standard resurrection where lycanthropy still applies.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver: According to this [FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9utx), a [Figment Familiar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar/familiar-archetypes/figment-familiar-archetype/#) cannot be an [Improved Familiar](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-Familiar/#), because the Figment archetype replaces "Speak with Animals of its Kind".

Comment: Ok, that can be remedied, but the question remains the same. What occurs when a figment familiar is cursed, diseased, or poisoned dies and returns when the master regains/prepares their spells?

Answer (score 5):

### RAW

RAW it's unclear how it should be handled, as there is neither direct rules text from the **Recurring Dream** ability itself, nor indirect rules text from some place else to apply, nor a similar creature to compare it to.

---

### RAI

Trying to guess the rules as intended for **Recurring Dream** can be done from two places:

First, the [Summon Guardian Spirit](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Summon%20Guardian%20Spirit) feat is the most similar source of a creature that is the same, both in terms of being created from a base familiar as well as the penalty of not being able to be brought forth until a day has passed.

This Guardian Spirit is a summon and thus the [Summoning](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDefinitions.aspx?ID=23) subschool rules give some clues. The fact that after death the creature reforms and all spells of the summon expire likely means that it's a new creature, unaffected by previous conditions.

Second, by looking closely at **Manifest Dreams**, the other ability of a [Figment Familiar](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Familiar%20Figment), one can more easily guess what the intention of a Figment is:

> Manifest Dreams (Su): At 3rd level, a figment is shaped by its master’s dreams. Each time the master awakens from a full night’s rest, he can apply to the figment 1 evolution point’s worth of eidolon evolutions that don’t have a base form requirement. At 7th level, he can apply 2 points’ worth of eidolon evolutions; at 13th level, he can apply 3 points’ worth of eidolon evolutions.

I think this makes it very clear that the intention is for the Figment Familiar to be completely new every day. Because if we read **Recurring Dream** as the Figment keeping all its conditions (e.g. lycanthropy, poison, ...) upon reappearing, then we run into the problem that *it also keeps all the Eidolon evolutions that were applied previously*. After all, the **Manifest Dreams** ability RAW says nothing about the applied Eidolon evolutions ever disappearing either.

---

### Conclusion: A New Figment

This latter case of the Figment Familiar stacking Eidolon evolutions into infinity can safely be assumed to be false. And from this we can then deduct that the intention is for the Figment Familiar to be formed anew each day, without inheriting previous conditions or evolutions.

Comment: Excellent point, I would not have noticed that. On the other hand, I think it's strongly implied that the familiar's health remains the same while it's vanished; I would not assume that the familiar's health resets. Would you?

Comment: It does say when figment familiar dies, that it returns with 1 HP in stead of 1/4 it master's total HP when its master regains/prepare spells. I think that its counts as a reset in HP ,as it ends existing when it drops to 0 HP and comes back the next time it master regain spells with a single HP vs 1/4 its master's.

Comment: @Phoenices: I think even in those cases (when it vanishes from another source than death) the Figment returns completely anew (i.e. the health resets). The "returns with 1 hp" penalty seems to be the Figment's version of the way a Master can replace their dead familiar, which is usually a penalty in form of 200 gold per level.

Comment: You convinced me with your RAI argument, that I did not consider. +1